# Python script works on Mac not on Ubuntu

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, ubuntu

I have a python script that works on Mac and not on Ubuntu. When I run it in Ubuntu, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deploy.py", line 15, in <module>
    from modules.ima_python_utils import *
ImportError: No module named modules.ima_python_utils
```

It works on Mac, I don't know what's wrong.

**Ubuntu python version**

python 2.7.3

**Mac python version**

python 2.7.10

Here's my structure:

- modules

  - ima_python_utils

    - `__init__.py`
    - copy.py
    - ...
- deploy.py

**deploy.py**

```
import sys
import getopt
import os
import parser
import distutils.dir_util
import json
import subprocess
import ConfigParser

from modules.ima_python_utils import *
```

**`__init__.py`**

```
__all__ = ["copy", "file", "folder", "database"]
```

Comment: A decent guess is that `modules.ima_python_utils.file` imported as 'file'  is shadowing the built-in type `file`. I suspect you may be using different Python versions between platforms.

Comment: You might also check the sys.path on both systems if the top of the module is not in the path you can get weirdness with intra module imports I've found.

Comment: Also make sure you've got an `__init__.py` file inside the modules directory. The built in Python on OS X may be doing somethings nice for you.

Comment: You should really consider using less generic names that modules and file

Comment: What should be contained in __init__.py in modules, `__all__ = ["ima_python_utils"]` ?

Comment: I believe that the missing __init__ in modules was causing the error! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: is the folder containing **modules** in the Python path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to have an `__init__.py` inside the modules folder as well. I don't know why it was working on OS X but who knows.

Comment: While this answer was related to my issue I was also running 3.7 on Mac and 3.6 on Ubuntu.